# How would a collective recommendation letter from co-workers be perceived for admissions to MFA requiring work experience?

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, recommendation-letter

I am planning to apply to an MFA program in product design, and one of the admissions requirements is having at least 1 year of work experience.

My office is structured pretty horizontally (so, nobody is nobody's boss and we're all equals). We also do all our work collaboratively, in the open. I'm wondering if submitting a letter of recommendation written collectively by my entire team would make a statement to the admissions committee of this type of program.

Have any of you seen this? If any of you have been in charge of admitting students, what's your reaction?

Answer (score 1):

I had a "co-written" letter of recommendation when I was applying to graduate schools. I thought it was fine, and it was also somewhat unique, as did the people reviewing the application. The interviewer for one of the programs to which I was applying said that in two decades, he had never gotten such a letter before. So your letter will definitely stand out. However, there was also the comment that the letter was a bit strange and came across a bit "gimmicky."

I might recommend instead that you have one of your colleagues "officially" write the letter, and have the letter state that his co-workers (and name them!) also contributed to the content of the letter.